# How to convert JSON response to Java List- Using Rest Assured for API Testing

Tags: java, json, automation, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a nested JSON response. [JsonResponse Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V13lK.png)

I want to get the the dictionary at 0th location from the list and then get a particular element from it.
For e.g. In response, {0} and {1}, I want to get complete {0} as a result. Then from {0}, I want to extract "Id" value only.
I don't want to use the **JsonPath.read(JsonResponse String, JSON Path)** everytime. So looking for some simple and better alternative.

How to convert JSON response to Java List. Below is the response.

```
Response resp = given().header("Authorization", "Bearer "+"dwded").
                accept(ContentType.JSON).
                when().
                get("https://example.com");      
                return resp;
```

Comment: I'd write it in the editor.swagger.io and then have the editor generate the java code for you.

Comment: If you have a Java class which represents your response you could make use of Response#readEntity and then just access it like any other Java object

Comment: @Matthew Clark how to do that. Sorry I didn't get it. I am using Rest assured. Can it be used here?

Answer (score 0):

For testing a web-API or REST endpoint, I would recommend [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate).

So it becomes simple:

```
* def id = response[0].Id
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the new world. I wasn't aware about Karate. I am totally excited too use it now.

Comment: @DBhatnagar great, do spread the word. just curious why you accepted the other answer. do at least up-vote :P

Answer (score 0):

In the swagger editor pet example.

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation"
      schema:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
```

A model is generated from the

```
  Pet:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      name:
        type: "string"
        example: "doggie"
```

This generated a java class

```
public class Pet   {

  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name = null;
```

The api shows a REST that returns an entity that can be shown as an array of json objects

```
    ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> findPetsByStatus( @NotNull@ApiParam(value = "Status values that need to be considered for filter", required = true, allowableValues = "available, pending, sold") @RequestParam(value = "status", required = true) List<String> status);
```